# Java script isn't executing in my application

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax

Below is my Html Code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" CodeBehind="BranchRegistration.aspx.cs" Inherits="BloodBank.BranchRegistration" %>

    <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
        <div class="settings_pagecontent">
            <div class="addform">
                <asp:Button ID="BtnAdd" runat="server" CssClass="button" Text="Add" />
                <br />
                <br />
            </div>
            <div class="form">
                <div class="settings_border-line">
                    <div class="settings_label_left">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblbranchname" class="settings_label_inv" runat="server" Text="Branch Name"></asp:Label>
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <asp:Label ID="lblbranchphonenumber" class="settings_label_inv" runat="server" Text="Phone Number"></asp:Label>
                        <br />
                        <br />
                    </div>
                    <div class="text_right">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtbranchname" class="settings_textbox_body Branch_txt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
                        <br />
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtbranchphonenumber" class="settings_textbox_body" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                        <asp:Label ID="lblbranchemailid" class="settings_label_inv" runat="server" Text="Email ID"></asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtbranchemailid" class="settings_textbox_body" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
                <br />
                <br />

                <div class="border-line">
                    <div class="label_left" style="width: 150px">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblbranchaddress" class="settings_label_inv" runat="server" Text="Branch Address"></asp:Label>
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <asp:Label ID="lblbranchlandmark" class="settings_label_inv" runat="server" Text="Landmark"></asp:Label>
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <asp:Label ID="lblTehsil" class="settings_label_inv" runat="server" Text="Tehsil"></asp:Label>
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <asp:Label ID="lblbranchstate" class="settings_label_inv" runat="server" Text="State"></asp:Label>
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <asp:Label ID="lbllocationmap" class="settings_label_inv" runat="server" Text="Location"></asp:Label>
                        <br />
                        <br />
                    </div>
                    <div class="text_right" style="width: 670px">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtbranchaddress" class="settings_textbox_body" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblbranchstreet" class="settings_label_inv" runat="server" Text="Street"></asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtbranchstreet" class="settings_textbox_body" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtbranchlandmark" class="settings_textbox_body" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblbranchlocality" class="settings_label_inv" runat="server" Text="Locality"></asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtbranchlocality" class="settings_textbox_body" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txttehsil" runat="server" class="settings_textbox_body"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblDistrict" class="settings_label_inv" runat="server" Text="District"></asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDistrict" runat="server" class="settings_textbox_body"></asp:TextBox>
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlState" runat="server" class="settings_textbox_body"></asp:DropDownList>

                        <asp:Label ID="lblbranchpincode" class="settings_label_inv" runat="server" Text="Pincode"></asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtbranchpincode" class="settings_textbox_body" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtbranchlocationmap" class="settings_locationmap" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <asp:Button ID="invSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
                        <asp:Button ID="invReset" runat="server" Text="Reset" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="grid">
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('<%=txttehsil.ClientID%>').autocomplete({
                    source: function (request, response) {
                        $.ajax(
                            {

                                type: "POST",
                                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                url: "BranchRegistration.aspx/GetNames",
                        data: "{'name':'" + $('<%=txttehsil.ClientID%>').val() + "'}",
                                dataType: "json",
                                success: function (data) {
                                    response(data.d);
                                },
                                error: function (err) {
                                    alert("Error: " + err);
                                }
                            });
                    }, minLength: 1
                });
            });
        </script>
        <link href="Content/site1.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </asp:Content>
```

And server side code is as follow:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod] 
            public static List<string> GetNames(string name) 
            { 
                List<string> nameList = new List<string>();

                string strSqlQuery = "Select * from SubRegions where SubRegionName like '%" + name + "%'";
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(strSqlQuery, Common.GetConnectionString());
                DataSet ds = new DataSet(); da.Fill(ds, "SubRegions");
                DataTable dt = ds.Tables["SubRegions"]; 
                DataRowCollection drc = dt.Rows; 
                foreach (DataRow dr in drc)
                {
                    nameList.Add(dr["SubRegionName"].ToString()); 
                } 
                return nameList; 
            }
```

This code is run without a master page, but it is not run in my application. Please give me proper answer. In this page `autocomplete` textbox is use.It is `jquery ajax application`. I use this code in another project its execute properly and gave me proper result.

Comment: Any Error in `console`?

Comment: can you show us error? you can use firebug to catch error. or use ctrl+shft+j in chrome

Comment: The javascript is not execute in this application. The autocomplete textbox nothing  show any result. Its work like simple textbox.

Comment: remove your code and place simple alert to check if it is working.

Comment: Have you included the jquery file and autocomplete js files.

Comment: if this is working then you need to include the js files for autocomplete.may be you can place them in your master page file. be sure to put jquery related files before using any autocomplete related js

Comment: Sorry.     This is console error:         $(...).autocomplete is not a function.Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.

Comment: your jquery is not loading . i guess. place the jquery files in head tag and then autocomplete after it.show me the code

Comment: I added js file, but not working.

Comment: did you try to put alert in $(document).ready. if alert pops up then i will believe your Jquery is working

Comment: Yes, Alert is working.

Comment: Master header is:  <head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title><%: Page.Title %> - My ASP.NET Application</title>

    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
        <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
    <webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Content/css" />
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>

Comment: use   <asp:TextBox clientIdMode="static" ID="txttehsil" runat="server" class="settings_textbox_body"></asp:TextBox>  and in js function use $("#txttehsil") instead of  $('<%=txttehsil.ClientID%>'). This might help.  also add these. 1) <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
2) <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>. and remove urs. This is just for testing

Comment: Please give me answer. I am trying since 15 days.

Comment: remove your scripts and try to use these.1) <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script> 2) <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

Add "System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethodAttribute()" in your server code, the problem is solved.

your sever code look like this

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod ,System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethodAttribute()] 
public static List<string> GetNames(string name)
{ 
     List<string> nameList = new List<string>();
     string strSqlQuery = "Select * from SubRegions where SubRegionName like '%" + name + "%'";
     SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(strSqlQuery, Common.GetConnectionString());
     DataSet ds = new DataSet(); da.Fill(ds, "SubRegions");
     DataTable dt = ds.Tables["SubRegions"]; 
     DataRowCollection drc = dt.Rows; 
     foreach (DataRow dr in drc)
     {
         nameList.Add(dr["SubRegionName"].ToString()); 
     } 
     return nameList; 
}
```